# Issue with Dataweave component flow deployment on standalone server

Tags: mule

The application will not deploy on standalone server which having data weave component in my flow. But when my application designed in anypoint studio 5.4.1 its deployed in standalone run time. But now I am using Anypoint studio 6.0.0.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

`Dataweave` component is `Premium component` and it will not run in `Community Edition` version of Mule Standalone server, you will need Mule `Enterprise Edition` version. By default, Anypoint Studio runs `Mule EE Runtime` hence you won't see any issues while using the premium components such as `Dataweave`.